# Unable to delete virtual host in Wampserver because the storage device the virtual host was in got corrupted

Tags: wampserver

I have been using Wampserver to work on a website and for some reason the storage device that the website was in got corrupted. Now I need to use Wampserver again and can’t do it because the icon won’t turn green due to the virtual host that I haven’t been able to delete. What I need to do is delete the virtual host that is preventing Wampserver from turning green. Can anybody help me please? I have Wampserver 3.1.9 64bit.

I have tried reinstalling all services in the tools menu, but it didn't do the trick. I have googled the problem but there's nothing about it.

Comment: Yes, and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually remove a WAMPServer Virtual Host.

1. Stop WAMPServer.
2. Edit `wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.xx\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. Find and remove the `<VirtualHost> ...... </VirtualHosts>` that defined the virtual host that you are having problems with.

**Dont remove the VirtuaHost for localhost**

> If you are using WAMPServer 32bit the folder may be called `wamp` rather than just `wamp64`

Now you should be able to restart WAMPServer